# Invalid provider name "Default" for SitefinityMembershipProvider specified in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, membership-provider, sitefinity

> Invalid provider name "Default" for SitefinityMembershipProvider specified in web.config file. The name should match one of the providers configured in Sitefinity's Security.config configuration.

I am trying to use sitefinity membership in my asp.net web application to validate users. 
I have a sitefinity database with users and roles. Membership is working in sitefinity project but its not working in external website.

I copied all the DLL's from bin folder and all files in App_Data/Sitefinity/Configuration to external asp.net web application.

Also added Provider in web.config

```
  <membership defaultProvider="Default">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="Default" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Data.SitefinityMembershipProvider, Telerik.Sitefinity"/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
  </membership>
```

In the SecurityConfig configuration file also added Membership section

```
 <membership defaultProvider="Default">
<providers>
<clear/>
<add name="Default" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Data.SitefinityMembershipProvider, Telerik.Sitefinity"/>
</providers>
</membership>
```

In the login button click event i am trying to use

```
        System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider mp =     System.Web.Security.Membership.Providers["default"];
        var rtn = mp.ValidateUser("admin", "123456");

        if (rtn)
        {
            Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.UserManager um = Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.UserManager.GetManager();
            var user = um.GetUser(Model.Username);
        }
```

to validate the user but it throws error.

**Source code Link** :http://www.mediafire.com/?luo87fxigvx4amd

Comment: Can you show the relevant sections of the Config? It looks like something may not be configured right.

Comment: hi kevin i have added config sections

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what your problem is but you need to make sure you have pulled across all the Sitefinity and OpenAccess assemblies to your bin folder.

Also, as per this thread http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums/sitefinity-4-x/sdk/reference-sitefinity-dll-s-from-external-site.aspx - "Sitefinity components rely on the configuration, which is no longer stored in web/app config, but rather in separate configuration files in app_data" so you will need to pull these across as well.

However, the recommended approach would be to build a web service (http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums/sitefinity-3-x/developing-with-sitefinity/creating-users-with-sitefinity-api.aspx#1162552).

Comment: I just need to validate the user against Sitefinity datatbase.Ya i pull across all the ddl's and config files